# Azure AAD Need admin approval

Tags: azure, flutter, azure-active-directory

I created an app in azure and authenticating using AAD ,but when users try to log in they keep getting message admin approval required But no matter how I configure the application in the Azure Portal, I'm always receiving the following message after I've logged in with a normal user but an admin can login without the app showing the error,:

[image]

My Enterprise applications | User settings

[image]

My API permissions
[image]

I need my users to just login normally like the admin,  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What permissions does your app require?

Comment: read user profile

Comment: Is this a multi-tenant application? Are the users from this same tenant as where the app is registered?

Comment: Please share screenshot of required permission from **app registration->your application->Api permissions**

Comment: Hi @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity i have added, and it is a multitenant application

Comment: @juunas it is a multitenant when it was registered

Comment: If you are using `/common` or `/organizations` as the authority in the app, the user will authenticate against their home tenant. It might be what is happening here. Your tenant's settings will not apply there, and they may be required to give admin consent.

Comment: Hi @juunas after setting the admin consent to yes it worked

Comment: Hi @juunas do you mind moving your comment to the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been resolved by @juunas comment, post it as an answer to close the question.

> If you are using /common or /organizations as the authority in the
> app, the user will authenticate against their home tenant. It might be
> what is happening here. Your tenant's settings will not apply there,
> and they may be required to give admin consent.

The solution is to set the admin consent to: **"Yes"**