# How to implement user consent in applications multitenant registered with Azure AD B2 with microsoft graph to access Microsoft Calendar API?

Tags: javascript, azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have tried registering the application on Azure AD B2C by selecting the option "Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)". I chose this option so that all personal accounts or work accounts from any tenant can log in.

However, selecting this option creates Delegated permissions on Microsoft Graph when adding API permissions only has the option for openid, as in the image below.
VIEW IMAGE:
[Request API Permissions - Microsoft Graph - Delegated permissions type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgQhp.png)

therefore, I added calendars.read with application permissions type. VIEW IMAGE:
[Request API Permissions - Microsoft Graph - Application permissions type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqVIS.png)

The API permission has also been granted admin permission. VIEW IMAGE:
[Grant admin consent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adEnB.png)

[image]

the dependencies I use are "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.16.1"

and here's how I implemented it into my javascript code:

```
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: envconfig.REACT_APP_MICROSOFT, //Application (client) ID
    redirectUri: envconfig.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: envconfig.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
  },
};

const msalRequest = { scopes: ["user.read", "calendars.read"] };
const msalClient = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

async function MsalLogin() {
  try {
    const authResult = await msalClient.loginPopup({
      scopes: msalRequest.scopes,
      prompt: "select_account",
    });

    localStorage.setItem("_microsoftAccount", authResult.account.username);

    return authResult;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("MsalLogin error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}`
```

with the configuration above, when I as a user who is a member of a different tenant (Azure AD) tries to enter the application, and displays Need admin approval in the popup.
VIEW IMAGE:
[Need admin approval - error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc6Ac.png)

## **Question:**

What configurations are appropriate to do in an Azure AD B2C environment and how to implement them in JavaScript coding, so that users with work or personal accounts from any tenant can connect their calendars to my application with consent by the user or if possible without requiring approval from any party . So that admins from the user's organization don't have to approve logging into my app?

If anyone understands this, please help. Let me know if there is any other information I should share.

## **What i have tried:**

- I have tried registering a new application by selecting "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant – Multitenant)". With this option, delegated permissions have the option to add more api permissions, including calendars.read. After I apply it, it still displays Need admin approval.
- I have tried to find out about verified publisher to solve this problem, but I am not sure because Azure AD B2C does not have this feature
- i have tried adding a user flow with type signupsignin, but i don't understand how to implement it, and whether this way will solve my problem.
- I have tried changing the Admin consent settings by changing to Yes
  in the Users can request admin consent to apps they are unable to
  consent to option, but it doesn't work

## **What i expected :**

I want my application to be accessible by any tenant and with personal Microsoft accounts or work accounts. And also I want to use the graph API and make the permissions must be approved from the user's side, so that the admin doesn't need to give permission first so that the popup doesn't appear Need admin approval.

Screenshot of settings in my azure:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Option for add API Permission - User
[image]

Comment: Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise application -> Consent and permissions -> User consent settings -> Enable the option Allow user consent for apps -> Save like  [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/qnkIZEt.png)

Comment: Hi @Rukmini 
Thanks for your response. 'Allow user approval for apps' is already enabled, but still shows Need admin approval.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78023687/azure-entra-id-authentication-requiring-admin-consent/78025010?noredirect=1#comment137559154_78025010

Comment: @Rukmini I've tried it, but it doesn't work. For additional information, that I am logged in to Azure and have 2 directory access, let's call them directories A and B, my account is registered as a member in directory A and I am a global admin in directory B. Directory B (owned by the client - Azure AD B2C) is where I registered application. When I enter the application using my account registered in directory A, it causes Need admin approval.

Comment: When I changed the Azure settings in directory B according to your solution, it had no impact. should this setting be done in directory A? If yes, is there a way to work around this from the Azure settings in my directory, so that my app can be entered by users from any organization that has admin consent settings? correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank You.

Comment: Which directory does your app resides in?

Comment: @Rukmini in directory B which is Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Yes you have to do the settings in directory B only and could you paste the screenshots?

Comment: Hi @Rukmini sorry for late reply. I have edited the question above by adding a screenshot of my settings in Azure. If there is anything missing let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You are passing scope as "user.read", "calendars.read" but dint grant API permission "user.read" to the application. Please grant user.read API permission and check if that works. Let me know I will post it as an answer

Comment: @Rukmini The problem is that the option for user.read is not in the application permissions like the image I added in the question above. if I give a scope just like this: ["user.read"] in my code, login was successful, but failed to access the calendar. When i encoded the access token, scp only has this value : "scp": "openid profile User.Read email". i think the cause of the problem is calendars.read on the scope. but I don't know where the error lies, because this scope has been approved by the admin at Azure

Comment: As you are using interactive flows only delegated type API permissions will be displayed in scp not Application type API permission

Comment: Azure B2C doesn't support calendars.read delegated API permission hence you are getting error

Comment: Alternatively you can create Azure AD application and add calendars.read delegated API permission to resolve the error

Comment: @Rukmini What does it mean to create Azure AD application? does that mean i can't use calendars.read as a delegated permission with Azure AD B2C?

Comment: Yes you cant use calendars.read as a delegated permission with Azure AD B2C

Comment: @Rukmini is there no other way to solve this problem in Azure AD B2C environment?

or is the only way to use the calendars.read API is to register the application only in the directory with the Azure AD service?

and how do I know if a directory uses the Azure AD service?
because I'm not sure whether directory A that I mentioned previously uses the Azure AD service.

Comment: In Azure AD B2C directory create the application by selecting "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant – Multitenant)" option

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/661726/azure-ad-b2c-token-issue-while-calling-microsoft-g

Comment: @Rukmini I have also tried this before, indeed by selecting that option, the calendars.read in delegated permissions are exist, but still when logging in Microsoft displays Need admin approval.

Comment: Can you test it via Postman by generating token and calling the API?

Comment: And with which account are you signing in?

Comment: Okay i will test it via Postman, and let you know later. I signing in with an office account which is a member of directory A that I previously mentioned.

Comment: If you are using /common or /organizations as the authority in the app, the user will authenticate against their home tenant. Your tenant's settings will not apply there, and they may be required to give admin consent. Hence check the settings in another directory too

Comment: @Rukmini okay I understand, thank you so much for helping me. I will discuss this with my coworkers.

Comment: I will post it as an answer for the clear steps let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: Any user singing in will authenticate against their home tenant settings not the application residing tenant. If you are making use of `common` or `organizations` to authenticate the user, then make sure the user residing tenant have the proper settings.

I created an **application in Azure B2C tenant** by selecting *"Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant – Multitenant)"* option:

[image]

Granted below API permissions:

[image]

The user consent settings the B2C tenant (*where the app resides*) is set like below:

[image]

In another directory, I added the user like below:

[image]

When I tried to sign in with another directory user, I got the **same error**:

[image]

Hence **to resolve the error**, you have to change the user consent settings in the directory where the user resides like below:

*Set Admin consent requests to YES*:

[image]

The user must request for the access:

[image]

*Once the request is approved, the user will be able to sign in successfully*

***Otherwise***, Grant **tenant wide admin consent** by signing in as Global administrator (*Global Admin of user residing tenant*):

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/adminconsent ?client_id=ClientIDofB2CApp&scope=User.Read Calendars.Read&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms &state=12345
```

The user will be able to successfully login:

[image]

**Reference:**

[flutter - Azure AAD Need admin approval - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119472/azure-aad-need-admin-approval) by junnas

Comment: Thank you for your help, your solution makes everything clearer. However, changing settings in the user's tenant needs to be discussed first by my team.